# Помогите разобраться с api сервиса

Tags: node.js, api, сокет

Мне необходимо получать инфу с канала 'newitems_cs', в принципе все(закрашенное не нужно).
Сервер: wss://wsn.dota2.net/wsn/
Мой код (он не работает):

```
 const ws = new WebSocket('wss://wsn.dota2.net/wsn/');
 ws.onopen = (data)=>{
    ws.send('newitems_cs');
    ws.on('newitems_cs', (data)=>{
        console.log(data);
    })
 }
```

[image: вырезка с апи]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовал пакет ws - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

```
const webSocket = require("ws");
const ws = new webSocket('wss://wsn.dota2.net/wsn/');

ws.on('open', function open() {
  console.log('Connection open')
  ws.send('history_cs');
});

  ws.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log(message);
  });
```

Comment: да, вы правы, точно такой же код час назад взял у другого человека)